# Load bitmapImage from base64String

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, bitmapimage

How can I load a `bitmapImage` from `base64String` in `windows 8`?

I tried this but I am not successful. It used to work on windows phone. What is different?

Looks like I have to use the function setsourceasync. When I use that, then I am required to pass the parameter as IRandomMemory which I am unable to do. How to do this?

```
    public static BitmapImage Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(base64String))
            {
                var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
                {
                    bitmapImage.SetSourcec(ms);
                    return bitmapImage;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Windows 8 metro apps can be programmed in several programming languages. Which one are you using?

Comment: c# sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: Why are you "not successful"?

Comment: I am unable to convert memory stream into bitmap image. Looks like I have to use the function setsourceasync. When I use that, then I am required to pass it as IRandomMemory which I am unable to do. How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create an **IRandomAccessStream** object for the **SetSource** method, you need to use a **DataWriter**. Take a look to this code:

```
    public async Task<BitmapImage> GetImage(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        var buffer = System.Convert.FromBase64String(value);
        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(ms.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
            {
                writer.WriteBytes(buffer);
                await writer.StoreAsync();
            }

            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(ms);
            return image;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Probably my `byte[]` source is incorrect. Do you have a method to convert from `BitmapImage` to `Base64`?

Answer (score 0):

Here conversion methods for both System.Drawing.Bitmap and System.Windows.Media.BitmapSource.

Enjoy

Remark: Not tested on Win8 but there is not reason why it should not work.

```
    string ToBase64(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if (bitmap == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bitmap");

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    string ToBase64(BitmapSource bitmapSource)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
            encoder.Save(stream);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    Bitmap FromBase64(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(value)))
        {
            return (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
    }

    BitmapSource BitmapSourceFromBase64(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(value)))
        {
            var decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            BitmapSource result = decoder.Frames[0];
            result.Freeze();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work for windows 8, the windows 8 follows .Net4.5, maybe some of these functions do not exist. Please check your answer once again. Waiting for the right one :(

Comment: `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Media` are not available for Windows Store Applications.