# BitmapSource to Bitmap Returns Null( EmguCV2.4.2.1777 + Kinect )

Tags: c#, kinect, emgucv

Hy, 
I am trying to convert BitmapSource to Bitmap from Kinect RGB Color Stream. I am getting null.
I am using Kinect for Windows SDK 1.6, Visual Studio 2012, Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, EmguCV 2.4.2.1777.
Here is the Code:

```
void _kinect_ColorFrameReady( object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e )
    {
        using ( ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame() )
        {
            if ( colorFrame == null )
            {
                return;
            }

            if ( colorFrame != null )
            {
                this.colorPixels = new byte[colorFrame.PixelDataLength];

                colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo( this.colorPixels );

                int stride = colorFrame.Width * 4;

                colorBmp = BitmapSource.Create( 
                    colorFrame.Width, 
                    colorFrame.Height, 
                    96, 
                    96, 
                    PixelFormats.Bgr32, 
                    null, 
                    colorPixels,
                    stride 
                );

                currentColorFrame = new Image<Bgr, Byte>( colorBmp.ToBitmap() );

                this.imgOutput.Source = ImageHelpers.ToBitmapSource( currentColorFrame ); 
            }
        }           
    }
```

Helper Methods:

```
   public static System.Drawing.Bitmap ToBitmap(this BitmapSource bitmapsource)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap;
        using ( var outStream = new MemoryStream() )
        {
            // from System.Media.BitmapImage to System.Drawing.Bitmap
            BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add( BitmapFrame.Create( bitmapsource ) );
            enc.Save( outStream );
            bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap( outStream );
            return bitmap;
        }         
    }


    [DllImport("gdi32")]
    private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert an IImage to a WPF BitmapSource. The result can be used in the Set Property of Image.Source
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image">The Emgu CV Image</param>
    /// <returns>The equivalent BitmapSource</returns>
    public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(IImage image)
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Bitmap source = image.Bitmap)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = source.GetHbitmap(); //obtain the Hbitmap

            BitmapSource bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                ptr,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            DeleteObject(ptr); //release the HBitmap
            return bs;
        }
    }
```

Please point out my mistake or give me any suggestion as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return statement in your ToBitmap method as follows. [See also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529301/load-bitmapimage-from-base64string/13530394#13530394).

```
return (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(stream)
```

Be aware, that CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap in your ToBitmapSource can cause a memory leak. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546091/wpf-createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap-memory-leak). There are many other ways to convert a Bitmap to a BitmapSource but for my experience none is faster.

Answer (score 0):

A [quick search](http://www.google.com/search?q=bitmapsource%20to%20bitmap&aq=f&oq=bitmapsource%20to%20bitmap&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) yielded several resources on how to convert a `BitmapSource` to a `Bitmap`.

[Is there a good way to convert between BitmapSource and Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284353/is-there-a-good-way-to-convert-between-bitmapsource-and-bitmap)

http://snipplr.com/view/63090/how-to-convert-bitmapsource-to-bitmap/

https://gist.github.com/916300

They all follow a general theme, though slightly different.

Comment: I have done all these before coming here. :) I don't know, why i am getting null.I think, It's because of EmguCV 2.4. In emguCV 2.3 it works well.

Comment: That is odd.  Are you using EmguCV for anything else, or just this operation?

Comment: For detection and recognition as well.

Answer (score 0):

As you are on a 64bit OS, m hoping that you have referred the following files too (For EMGU CV version >=2.4)

`cudart64_42_9.dll, cvextern.dll, npp64_42_9.dll`

This will help in using emgucv in 64bit OS if you are not doing a 64bit build.
Other than that your code look fine.